# Move latex questions to tex SE site

Tags: discussion

Lately I noticed many good question under the [latex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex) and some of them (correctly for SO) are flagged as off-topic.

In my opinion should be moved to [tex.stackoverflow](http://tex.stackoverflow) community, which is their rightful place. As a user of the 'Related' (that list on the right sidebar) functionality I find this migration will 'enhance' those questions. The tex community is growing bigger and many question can find answer there (duplicates also are going to exist), also I think is better from moderation perspective.

To SO users
What do you think about that? Does anyone has the same thoughts?

To Moderators
Is that even possible, to migrate all or the most tex related question to another SE site and then burnitate any leftover tags

Comment: Pretty sure similar requests/suggestions have been met with an answer of "We don't want to artificially inflate other, smaller SE sites with questions moved from SO." Also worth noting that anything older than 60 days cannot be migrated, except by SE devs and only under extremely special circumstances.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of posts that should stay and should be migrated?

Comment: What's it harming if they stay here, honestly?

Comment: @Kendra In my humble opinion is not inflation, is considered better organization. I think thats way there are several sites. I was not fully aware of the '60 days rule'

Comment: @Athafoud But it _is_ artificially inflating the newer site with more questions than were actually asked there. Those posts being moved to the newer site would make it look like the newer site has more activity than it truly does. Granted, that might not actually _break_ anything, but it still wouldn't be an accurate representation of how active the site truly is. There are several sites so that the sites can each have a specific scope. In some cases, such as this, that scope can overlap. When there's overlap, there is absolutely no reason to say you must ask on one site, not the other.

Comment: @Makoto due times, I have found a lot cross-site dublicates and as I said I think is better both for whom who asks and the one who answers, to have everything in one place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not every question with the [latex] tag should be migrated off of Stack Overflow. For many, LaTeX is but a part of a larger programming question.

Also, only questions that are up to 60 days old can be migrated, so any ones beyond that point can't be sent across even by a moderator.

The higher-rep users of TeX.SE have been very good about identifying questions worth migrating, and we've handled these as they have been found. I don't see a need to mass-migrate many more questions beyond that.

Comment: Your last paragraph (The higher-rep users of TeX.SE have ...) answers the most of my question.